# UnovaRPG automator: Selenium Python image error

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firebug

I am trying to make a python program using Selenium to automate the [UnovaRPG](https://www.unovarpg.com/) game. It is supposed to do the following in order:

*1) Login with username and password.*

*2) Go to heal center and click heal.*

*3) Fight the trainer "shedinja144" (using given link)*

*4) Select a specified pokemon.*

*5) During the fight, it should click the last attack followed by continue.*

*6) Then click "Back to map" for the last pokemon (The 6th).*

*7) Repeat steps 2-5 any given number of times.*

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.unovarpg.com/login.php")
assert "UnovaRPG" in driver.title
i=1
j=1

typeUsername = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
typePassword = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

typeUsername.send_keys("******")
typePassword.send_keys("******")
driver.find_element_by_id("buttonLogin").click()

while i<10:
    driver.get("https://www.unovarpg.com/pokemon_center.php")
    driver.find_element_by_id("healButton").click()
    driver.get("https://www.unovarpg.com/battle.php?type=autotrainer&tid=5546527")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/div[4]/div[1]/img").click()
    while j<6:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[6]/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a/strong").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("continue").click()
        j+=1
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[6]/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a/strong").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("Back2MapButton").click()
    i+=1
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Selenium v1.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/div[4]/div[1]/img").click()
  File "E:\Programming\Python\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 230, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "E:\Programming\Python\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/div[4]/div[1]/img"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/adb/appdata/local/temp/tmpo1kmq3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9641:26)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///c:/users/adb/appdata/local/temp/tmpo1kmq3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9650:3)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/adb/appdata/local/temp/tmpo1kmq3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11635:16)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/adb/appdata/local/temp/tmpo1kmq3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11640:7)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/adb/appdata/local/temp/tmpo1kmq3/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11582:5)

***Repl Closed***
```

The error lies in the inability to find the image of the pokemon to click (Step 4). I have used the xcode path copied from the Firebug inspector.

Help would be much appreciated.

**Please note that this is just for creative purposes and will not be used to "cheat".**

Comment: http://www.sikuli.org/ might be a more appropriate platform for something like this than python

Answer (score 0):

You need to [explicitly wait for the element to load](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) before interacting with it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/div[4]/div[1]/img"))
)
```